# Can't edit read only file even when root

Tags: macos

I am trying to edit `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.taskgated.plist` on OS X El Capitan. The file permissions are

`-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  601 17 Nov  2015 com.apple.taskgated.plist`

My first try was `sudo vi (filename)` and then use `w!` after editing but vi still reports read only status.

My second try was to use nano with sudo - same problem.

My third try was `sudo su` then edit the file - same problem.

My fourth try was `vi (filename)`, write as temporary file then `sudo cp (temp file) (filename)` - operation not permitted.

I would like to know a) how to fix the problem and b) what I have misunderstood - I thought that I have full root access via `sudo` or `sudo su` and root has write permission on this file...

Comment: The file may be marked as immutable (Linux)/unchangeable (OS X).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unless you have already disabled [System Integrity Protection](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-os-x-10-11), the `/System` directory tree will not be writable even by root.

Issue `ls -lO /System` (capital letter 'oh', not zero); if you see `restricted`, SIP is protecting that directory tree.

Solution (from the linked answer):

1. First boot into recovery mode (Command-R during boot)
2. In the terminal, issue `csrutil disable`
3. Reboot to normal mode.  You should see that SIP is no longer blocking write access.

If you later want to restore SIP, just use `csrutil enable` in recovery mode.

Answer (score 1):

my guess is that you were using vim on a mac to edit a system file. Try using nano instead. It worked for me.

Comment: what? how is this the correct answer? what's wrong with mac? anyway thanks for this. +1

Comment: Can't save it in Catalina with either vim or nano.

Comment: Using nano instead of vi ended up working for me. It looked like vi wasn't triggering whatever OSX popup was needed that I have to click 'allow' on in order to write the final file

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the file is not open by another process that might be blocking it.

```
lsof +D /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but it doesn't seem to be explicitly open by another program.

Answer (score 0):

Check if all folders leading to the file you want to edit exist! That is what had happened to me :)

```
vim ~/some_folder/some_non_existing_folder/file.txt
```