# Can't edit readonly file even when root AND without System Integrity Protection

Tags: macos-ventura

`Note:` This question is different than: [Can't edit read only file even when root](https://superuser.com/questions/1159290/cant-edit-read-only-file-even-when-root)

I am trying to edit `/System/Library/QuickLook/Illustrator.qlgenerator/Contents/Info.plist`.

On `MacOS Ventura` (Mac M1).  **I have already disabled [System Integrity Protection](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-macos)**.

```bash
❯ pwd
/System/Library/QuickLook/Illustrator.qlgenerator/Contents
❯ csrutil status
System Integrity Protection status: disabled.
❯ sudo chmod 777 Info.plist
Password:
chmod: Unable to change file mode on Info.plist: Read-only file system
```

What am I doing wrong here? [asciinema video](https://asciinema.org/a/2QdoC7k8uS8t6fT56bynZcB5H)

Comment: You cannot edit anything at all within the system partition, SIP or no SIP. The volume is sealed & checksummed. If you do manage to change anything in there, at next boot it will refuse to do anything except re-install a clean system [I'm sure this must be duplicated here somewhere already, but I can't find it at the moment, hence not an answer.]

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas The question/video shows that I am using root and disabled system integrity protection. So... I did not understand your point.

Comment: @Tetsujin I have found many places saying that you can edit if SIP is disabled.  Maybe this is something of Ventura?

Comment: It's been this way since Big Sur. See https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/security/secd698747c9/web and https://eclecticlight.co/2020/11/30/is-big-surs-system-volume-sealed/

Answer (score 1):

As @Tetsujin commented:
Since BigSur, the System Partition is `sealed` as `read-only` and one cannot change this even with root and disabled System Integrity Protection.

See:  [Apple documentation](https://%20support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/security/secd698747c9/web%20and%20eclecticlight.co/2020/11/30/is-big-surs-system-volume-sealed)